# Text does not render properly until field is clicked

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I'm using itext for editing PDF. I'm embedding font in the field. But text does not render properly until that field is clicked.
[link to the pdf](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1A3dFSHM9r3fLtRHUpFwlCDa6QOm5n-m8)

```
String unicodeFontPath = "templates/font/FreeSans.otf";
BaseFont unicode1 = BaseFont.createFont(unicodeFontPath, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
fields.setFieldProperty("Given Name Text Box", "textfont", unicode1, null);
fields.setField("Given Name Text Box", emp.getName());
```

Comment: Please share the pdf in question.

Comment: Please define *render properly*. I see no issues with the rendering, but then again, I can't see your PDF.

Comment: font is not getting applied to the text until field is cliked.

Comment: Obviously a screenshot doesn't help, it's the pdf one can analyze...